# Get Windows nmake version from command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-prompt, nmake

I don't really know `nmake`, but I use `nmake` from "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017" under Windows 10; I would like to find out the version of this tool from the command prompt.

I have found this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/batch-mode-rules?view=vs-2019

> To check the NMAKE version, run the _NMAKE_VER macro available with NMAKE version 1.62 or higher. This macro returns a string representing the Visual C++ product version.

... but I don't really know how to "run the macro" - I tried this:

```
C:\>nmake _NMAKE_VER

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.16.27026.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make '_NMAKE_VER'
Stop.
```

So, it dropped something like a version string, but there's still an error.

Thus, how can I get the `nmake` version from the command line properly?

Comment: Macros are for makefiles.  Consider typing `nmake /?`, it displays the version number and command options.

Comment: Thanks for that @HansPassant - feel free to post this as an answer, I'll accept it!

Comment: Hard to write a decent answer, I just have no idea why this is important to you.  Just share what you learned in your own post and mark it as the answer.

Comment: My answer to your `nmake` question gives, I think, a reasonable example of how to the use of the built-in macro `_NMAKE_VER`.

Answer (score 1):

As Hans Passant suggests, you could consider typing `nmake/?`; this will give you what you already know from your question, namely `14.16.27026.1`.

The point of the variable `_NMAKE_VER` is to allow you to test the `nmake` version, or the Visual Studio version, from *within* the makefile. For example, suppose your makefile is:

```
 # Check the first three characters of _NMAKE_VER to
 # obtain the Visual Studio version:
 !if [cmd /c if "%_NMAKE_VER:~0,3%"=="14." exit 1]
 !  message Using VS 2017, with NMAKE $(_NMAKE_VER)
 !elseif [cmd /c if "%_NMAKE_VER:~0,3%"=="12." exit 1]
 !  message Using VS 2013, with NMAKE $(_NMAKE_VER)
 !else
 !  message Unknown VS version, with NMAKE $(_NMAKE_VER)
 !endif

 # Just output _NMAKE_VER:
 all:
      @echo "Version             NMAKE" $(_NMAKE_VER)
```

Then issuing the following command from the Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt:

```
 nmake /nologo
```

will give (on my machine):

```
 Using VS 2017, with NMAKE 14.10.25019.0
 Version             NMAKE 14.10.25019.0
```

or for Visual Studio 2013:

```
 Using VS 2013, with NMAKE 12.00.21005.1
 Version             NMAKE 12.00.21005.1
```

We need to use the DOS `cmd` to inspect `_NMAKE_VER`, as `nmake` unlike `gmake` has limited string manipulation tools.

**Edit:** The above test will probably not be able to distinguish between VS 15 and VS 17, since the VS 17 `nmake` version number begins with `14` rather than the expected `15`.

Comment: **Edit:** To  distinguish between VS 15 and VS 17, you would have to do a more careful check of the subversion numbers, since the VS 17 `nmake` primary version number is `14` rather than the expected `15`.